# Can I detect when my class instance gets unset or garbage-collected?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

I have a PHP class that, upon instantiation, creates a file that is unique to that instance of my class. In fact, the entire class is more of a wrapper around the file with various functions to operate on the file.

I would like the file to get removed when the class is deleted/unset/garbage-collected. Is this possible? I'm looking for some sort of magic function that PHP calls on every object to give it a chance to get it's affairs in order before it's killed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a destructor method.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass {

   function __destruct() {
       print "This instance is being destroyed!!! :(( ";
   }
}
```